# Storing geo location in contract

Tags: contract-development, arrays, struct, constructor

I am beginner in solidity programming, I am trying to write my first contract. I am trying to store a piece of land (which is array of coordinates) against a person. I am having trouble storing the coordinates, How do I store geolocations in contracts? My data looks like this-

```
[
 [88.07945251464845,22.74733761475462], //each pair is a point on map
 [88.47633361816406,22.751136986888394],
 [88.4886932373047,22.56738007346293],
 [88.0986785888672,22.484926579266755],
 [88.07945251464845,22.74733761475462]
]
```

I have created a struct called coordinate -

```
struct coordinate {
        bytes32 lat;
        bytes32 long;
    }
```

I have no idea how to store a collection coordinate struct, I am using solidity version `^0.4.0`, and the documentation says we can't use array of structs in this version of solidity. Also how do I pass geolocation array to my constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

uint256 private constant RESOLUTION = 1000000000000000;

struct Coordinate {
    uint256 lat;
    uint256 long;
}

Coordinate[5] private coordinates;

constructor() public {
    coordinates[0] = Coordinate({lat: 8807945251464845, long: 22747337614754620});
    coordinates[1] = Coordinate({lat: 8847633361816406, long: 22751136986888394});
    coordinates[2] = Coordinate({lat: 8848869323730470, long: 22567380073462930});
    coordinates[3] = Coordinate({lat: 8809867858886720, long: 22484926579266755});
    coordinates[4] = Coordinate({lat: 8807945251464845, long: 22747337614754600});
}
```

You can use `RESOLUTION` as a denominator in your calculations, or alternatively run them off-chain.